# Can someone called for one of the Shabbat or Yom Tov aliyot be called again for maftir?

Tags: shabbat, torah-service, maftir

I think the title of the question is self-explanatory.Something to consider:

Maftir seems to be separate from the other aliyot specified in Talmud Megilah.

Would it matter if the person who had maftir was the same Cohen that received the Cohen aliyah, or Levi who received the same Levi aliyah?

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/65355

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears from the Aruch Hashulchan in the last line of  [סימן קמד - שלא לדלג בתורה מעניין לעניין, ודיני ההפטרה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01582.html#HtmpReportNum0143_L2)  that **in extenuating circumstances one could call up for Maftir a person who already had an Aliya**.

> . ובכלל אין לעשות כן שאחד יעלה שני פעמים אלא בשעת הדחק (שם). וכתבו דהמהרי''ל עלה ללוי וגם למפטיר, ואולי היה מוכרח לזה מאיזה טעם.‏

He doesn't specify what counts as extenuating circumstances.

Comment: Good thing I was able to locate this Q. My shul had a sit. last Shabbat where they had assigned a Levi maftir. (They assign maftir weeks in advance.) It turns out that he was the only Levi in the shul. (Usually, there are 2 others, but last week the others were out.) Not knowing what to do, the rabbi asked the Levi to leave and have the Cohen receive 2 aliyot.

Comment: I can think of an example of "extenuating circumstances" that occurs in my neighborhood. We have a shul in a nursing home. The majority of those in the minyan are people with limited mental capacity or no speech ability. In short, they cannot always get 7 **different** people for all the *aliyot*. Inevitably, they frequently need to call someone twice.